# jQuery tabs: How to avoid display of tabs while loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery tabs for displaying certain lists. I was able to make the tabs work. Apparently, it displays all the content while it loads the tabs.

Is there a way that I can avoid the loading display?

Comment: Initial CSS for the container: `display: none`.

Comment: can u post some code?

Comment: Can you get I bit more precisely on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the tabs, just give `style="display: none;"`:

```
<div class="tab" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Tab Content -->
</div>
```

And if you are using the default jQuery UI tabs, also add this to your CSS:

```css
.ui-tabs-hide {display: none;}
```

Comment: It worked for me. The jquery tabs was hidden as it the page loads. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can hide content with beforeLoad event and and show it after it being fully loaded.

Example :

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({

        /* before tab is loaded */
        beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
            $('#content').hide();

        },
        /* tab is loaded */
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $('#content').show();
        }
    });
});
```

or simply as praveen kumar described :

```
.ui-tabs-hide {display: none;}
```